# How can I plot the intersection of raw data points?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

So I am trying to plot the intersection of two lines that I have plotted. Thing is, is that each of these 2 lines are plotted by having two same-size lists and just lining up the values. Basically a time vs value for each line. What is the best way to go about this, I am trying my solution but it isn't working. I'm thinking of trying to put the raw data in the form of a function, but I'm not sure how to do that and I don't know how to do so. I'm using python 2.7.

So I am using these modules/packages:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import time
import bisect
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from spacepy import pycdf
```

Here is what I tried:

```
 def intersection(time,time_3A,L1,L2):
 #looks for times within a certain threshold of each other, and cechks if their values are within a certain thershold of each other. 
 #returns a list of tuples that contain points of approximate intersections 
    points = []
    for t in range(0, len(time) - 1,30):
        for  s in range(0, len(time_3A) - 1, 30):
            if abs(time[t] - time_3A[s]).seconds < 300 : 
                # print "T1:" + str(time[t])
                # print "T2:" + str(time[s])
                if abs(L1[t] - L2[s]) < .5 :
                    point = (time[t],L1[t])
                    points.append(point)
    return points
```

and I'm using matplotlib to plot my data : ax = plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(0, 0))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(1, 1))

Comment: as-is, you're appending duplicate `point`s  if they are near multiple `L2` values at a given time.  Is this intended?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am not intending to do so, it just seems that my way makes it duplicating inevitable.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Time is just another dimension. I think this should work by doing everything 4D

```
tdif = abs(time[:, None] - time_3A).seconds    #2d array of time differences
tmask = tdif < 300                             #2d array of booleans
Ldif = abs(L1[:, None] - L2)                   #2d array of distance
Lmask = Ldif < .5                              #2d array of booleans

mask = np.any(np.logical_and(tmask, Lmask), axis = 1)
points = np.c_[time[mask], L1[mask]]
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm having trouble because the elements in tdif have the method seconds() that return the datetime element in seconds. How can I access that through the tdif array, as you did there? And may you please explain what you did? I'm new to numpy.

Comment: Same way you did in your original code, I suppose.  Also fixed the duplication.